# coroutine before Python 3.4

Tags: python

I want to confirm the following questions:

1. There is no native coroutine decorator in Python 2. It would be provided by something like [[1]](http://dabeaz.com/coroutines/coroutine.py).
2. Prior to Python 3.4, all other Python 3 releases require `pip install asyncio` in order to use `import asyncio.coroutine` [[2]](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/#status).
3. [trollius](https://bitbucket.org/enovance/trollius) is the reference port implementation of aysncio and tulips for Python 2 (and the community thinks that's the one to use)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Python generators as coroutines, using only built-in methods. I have **not** used coroutines in any other environment, so my approach may be misinformed.

Here's some starter code I wrote that uses generators to send and receive data in a coroutine capacity, without even using Python 3's `yield from` syntax:

```
def sleep(timer, action=None):
    ''' wait for time to elapse past a certain timer '''
    yield   # first yield cannot accept a message
    now = then = yield
    while now - then < timer:
        now = yield
    if action:
        action()
    else:
        yield "timer finished"

def buttonwait():
    ''' yields button presses '''
    yield
    yield
    while True:
        c = screen.getch()
        if c:
            yield c
        yield
```

next, the wait function which manages the coroutines, sending the current time and listening for data

```
def wait(processes):
    start = time.time()
    for process in processes:
        process.next()
        process.send(start)
    while True:
        now = time.time()
        for process in processes:
            value = process.send(now)
            if value:
                return value
```

last, an implementation of those:

```
def main():
    processes = []
    process.append(timer(5)
    processes.append(buttonwait())
    wait(processes)
```

I used this on a Raspberry Pi with a 2x16 LCD screen to:

- respond to button presses
- turn off the backlight after a timeout
- scroll long text
- move motors
- send serial commands

---

It's a bit complicated to get started, knowing where to put the `yield`s and whatnot, but seems reasonably functional once it is.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your question, I think you've conflated two things: co-routines and async I/O-run loops. They do not depend upon each other.

Because in Python one can send values into a generator, you can create code implementing the co-routine pattern. All that is needed is `generator.send()`. Your link to David Beazley's code is a good example of how to create a co-routine. It is just a pattern. The new to Python v3.3 `yield from` allows this pattern to be used even more flexibly. David has an excellent talk on all of the things you can do with co-routines in a *synchronous* computing world.

Python's asyncio module depends upon the `yield from` construct. They have created an async co-routine to package this capability and associate it with a run loop. The goal, I believe, is to allow folks to easily build run loop oriented applications. There is still a role for the Twisteds and Tornados of the world.

(I myself am wary of projects like Trollius. They are kind of "Dancing Bear" project. They miss the point. Asyncio is about bringing a straightforward run loop implementation to Python 3 as a standard service. Python 2 already has two or more excellent async I/O libraries. Albeit these libraries are complex. IOW, if you are starting with Python 3 and your needs are straightforward, then use asyncio otherwise use Tornado. [Twisted isn't ported yet.] If you are starting with Python 2, then Twisted or Tornado is probably where you should start. Trollius? A code incompatible version with Python 3? An excellent "Dancing Bear.")

In my book, `asyncio` is an excellent reason to move your code to Python 3. We live in an asynchronous world and run loops are too important a feature to be project specific.

Anon,
Andrew